# Which .Phtml Containing Home Cart Counter in magento2?

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart

[image]

I Need to find out Home cart counter section  in magento 2 ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find **minicart.phtml** in your theme at

```
app\design\frontend\[NAMESPACE]\[THEME]\Magento_Checkout\templates\cart\minicart.phtml
```

**If not exist in your theme** then copy from `vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart\minicart.phtml` and do needful changes.

In **minicart.phtml** a `span` having a class `counter`, the data of counter coming as minicart icon in store front.

Comment: hi sir l'm already tested with som static values  in minicart.phtml, but the static values only display in checkout page

Comment: @ShafeelSha *static values only display in checkout page* not getting what you want to say you are looking for minicart, now you asking for checkout page, please provide more detail so i can help you.

Comment: sir i need to print  '123' values  for testing only my cart counter section . when i edit  minicart.phtml  it display in checkout and other pages also but not in home page !! why ?

Comment: @ShafeelSha if possible can you please share which magento version you are using and which theme, if possible can you share the dev url of your env where you want this code change so i can see. just share if possible so i can check and let you know

Comment: @ShafeelSha in class *counter-number* you can update the number or text that will come in store front

Comment: sir i'm using magento 2.3 with  porto theme, and i need to add total counts added in cart

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96205/discussion-between-shafeel-sha-and-kanhaiya-lal).